# Change image from meta title with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an image for logging in set with css, and want to change this to a logged out image when users are logged in. There is no variables to use, except a small change in the sites meta title. Would this be possible with vanilla Javascript?

the title:

```
<title>Text</title>
```

When logged in it adds, amongst the username a line

```
 <title>Text - </title>
```

css:

```
 .navLogin {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('/img/account.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
$("meta[property='yourProperty']").attr("content", newTitle);
```

**EDIT**

```
if(checkSomething()){

                var oldTitle = document.title;
                var newTitle = "NEW";
                document.title = oldTitle + newTitle;

                var link = document.createElement('link');      

                link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
                link.href = "example.jpg";
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
            }
```

Comment: I edit a little my first answer, is that useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to check if user is logged in based on tittle? Then:

```
if($('tittle').text() == loggedInTittle)
{
    //user is logged in so change image e.g
    $('.navLoggedOut').removeClass('.navLoggedOut').addClass('.navLogin');
}
```

Comment: Yes thats correct,Thanks! however, Doesnt seems to work for me.

Comment: Well nothing happends. I assume theres supposed to be an new class? might have written it wrong - where am i supposed to add my sites title text?

Comment: This code is just example, you need to store the tittle (after login) in loggedInTittle and have css class navLoggedOut that have background for logged out and navLogin for logged in

Comment: You can also modify that code to check for loggedOutTittle: if($('tittle').text() != loggedOutTittle) now it will also return true when user is logged in but this time it will check for loggedOutTittle